# Postfix behind AWS NLB with Proxy Protocol does not send banner until CRLF is sent

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix, amazon-eks

I've redeployed my mail stack as a Kubernetes pod. This pod is on an EKS cluster in the private subnet, behind an NLB. Postfix and the NLB are configured to speak proxy protocol v2.

Originally I had this setup without proxy protocol, and the Postfix ports responded as expected, immediately sending the Postfix banner upon connect, however Postfix could not identify the remote server sending mail to it correctly, and it marked everything as spam. So I've decided to go the proxy protocol route.

When connecting via telnet, the connection opens, but Postfix does not send it's banner. It's banner is not sent until a CRLF is sent (enter key is pressed) - You can send any other character and nothing will happen until the CRLF is sent. This affects the submission port on (587) and breaks client connections, as SMTP protocol declares the receiving server must respond first.

Initial connection:

```
❯ telnet mx01.example.com 587
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to mx01.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

After CRLF is sent:

```
❯ telnet mx01.example.com 587
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to mx01.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

220 mx01.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax
```

And this is without the Proxy Protocol configuration:

```
❯ telnet mx01.example.com 587
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to mx01.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx01.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

**Versions**:

OS: Ubuntu 20.10

Postfix version: 3.5.6-1

Postfix master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o cleanup_service_name=header_cleanup
  -o smtpd_upstream_proxy_protocol=haproxy
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
header_cleanup unix n   -       -       -       0       cleanup
 -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_cleanup.cf
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using postfix?  We use sendmail.  It is not hard to configure and we have found places where AWS implementations of SMTP were wrong and were able to force amazon to fix their product because we use sendmail.  Honestly, research the RFC that declares how the behavior is how to happen, then do a diag trace showing the SMTP conversation and t hen submit to amazon as a helpdesk ticket showing the RFC and how it is not working in their system.

Comment: This is a mail server. This isn't outbound mail from a webservice. Send mail is not appropriate for my use case.

Comment: Have you sent an SMTP debug to Amazon support?

Comment: I haven't mostly because I presume that their response will be something along the line of "we don't support your applications" as I suspect the issue is on the postfix side somehow

Comment: check if you already configured `postscreen` on your `main.cf`. edit your question to add `grep postscreen_upstream_proxy /path/to/main.cf` output.

Comment: Yes I did that. This issue affects both port 25 and submission on 587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this issue but not with Postfix, but with SSH (openssh <6.2).  I found out this post on SO that was related to the issue I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770798/awss-proxy-protocol-v2-breaking-application-due-to-absence-of-psh-flag. The answer posted there by dade describes a feature flag that you can set on the target group that fixed the issue on my side. I'm pretty sure it might be related to the issues you're seeing too!

Comment: This seems to have been the problem in my case as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

In that line, add -vvvv after second smtpd and restart postfix, you will have more logs and then you can see for what postfix is waiting or complaning.

I hope that this will help to move forward.

Thanks,

Comment: Did this before posting, nothing of note is revealed. Logs are quite normal.

Comment: Did you tried such solution? "We solved this problem by enabling postscreen on port 26, and forwarding port 25 on the ELB to port 26 on the instance, with Proxy Protocol enabled.

This allows our local clients to connect as normal via port 25 direct to the instance, and remote incoming mail to be processed by postscreen. " founded there http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/postscreen-upstream-proxy-protocol-with-both-proxied-and-unproxied-clients-td84489.html